# How does the automatic type conversion works with "char" in Java?

Tags: java, javac

I do not understand this behavior:

```
int i = 1;
char c = i; // compilation error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char

char c = 1; // is OK
```

provided that integer literals have default type int.

Comment: `i`, an integer, is a *wider* type than `char`.  As such it can't be assigned directly to a `char`.  An int can hold 2.4 billion positive values, a char only about 65,000.  That's why the assignment isn't allowed.  (Of course, you can cast `(char)` to let the compiler know you've thought about it and the assignment is OK.)

Comment: By the way, the `char` type is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the characters defined in Unicode. Learn to use Unicode code point integer numbers instead when working character-by-character.

Comment: This is bad advice by Basil and likely comes from some other language, like a C background.  `char` is still very much in use in Java and is the only choice you have for characters for most of the API.

Comment: @markspace Your first Comment would make a good Answer.

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm sure this question is a duplicate so we should find the canonical answer and then close this one with a link to the existing answer.

Comment: @markspace Methods to work with code points have been added to classes such as `Character`, `String`, and `StringBuilder`.

Comment: But `char` is not obsolete.  Most of the API still uses `char` and none of that is deprecated.

Comment: Duplicate of [Type cast vs literal assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431822/type-cast-vs-literal-assignment) and [How does implicit conversion work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62965817/how-does-implicit-conversion-work-in-java)

Comment: May be a duplicate of [*How to solve error lossy converion from int to char?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44257827/642706), but this Questionn here is shorter and simpler, and better.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I understand that "int" is wider than "char", but as i posted in the question - if i am right - default type of integer literals (in this case "1" in the third string - is the integer literal) is "int". For example:
`long l = 112147483647 // it is not working because the value is bigger than int maximum value and it will work only with l on the end`
`long l = 111; // is OK`
And in question's code - i try to assign char(c) with int(i) and it is not working, but with "1"(also int) - it works. And i do not understand why.  i will check the links above.

Comment: Thank you, @kaya3. This answer helped: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62966154/13991201) -> "Constant expression" part. So compiler is not fine with that "i" variable could be not in "char" range and "1" is always in char range. And in case with longs from mine previous comment - this is already connected to that integer literals have type "int" by default. So these are two separate things.

Answer (score 0):

char is 16 bits.
int is, at least, 32 bits.

you can not assign 32 (or more) bits into an 16 bit variable unless you down cast.

down cast example:

```
int kapow = 7;
char blam = (char)kapow;
```

Comment: Nope, Java defines chars as 16 bits and int as 32 bits.  There's no variability like in C.